# GLHT for multiple regression coefficients in R

Tags: r, glm

I have run a GLM binomial model

```
fit <- glm(highlow ~ V1 + V2 + V3 + V4 + V5 + V6 + V7 + V8 + V9 + V10,
       family="binomial")
```

To test the null hypothesis of V1 = V2 I have used the following code.

```
glht.mod <- glht(fit, linfct = c("V1 - V2 = 0"))
summary(glht.mod)
```

My question is can I test whether V1 = V2 = V3 (null hypothesis of all three coefficients being equal - note this is not the same as testing whether V1 = V2 and V2 = V3 in separate iterations)?

If it is any help, I am able to achieve this in SAS using the following code

```
proc logistic;
   model highlow = V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10;
   test1: V1 = V2;
   test2: V1 = V2 = V3;
run;
```

Comment: Looking at the SAS manual for the `test` statement in the proc `logistic` ( https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_logistic_sect025.htm ) you can find the assertion that "test3: test a1=a2=a3;   test4: test a1=a2, a2=a3;" are equivalent.

Comment: That is correct, but in both test3 and test4 in the SAS manual the tests are run in the same step. This is what I do not know how to do in R. I am able to do the equivalent in SAS of Test1 V1=V2; test2 V2=V3; What I am unable to do is Test1 V1=V2=V3; or if you prefer Test1 V1=V2, V2=V3;

Comment: Thanks. It looks like that is the solution I was after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibile solution for your problem:

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 1000
highlow <- factor(runif(n)>0.5)
X <- matrix(rnorm(n*10),nrow=n)
df <- data.frame(highlow, X)
names(df) <- c("highlow", paste("V",1:10,sep=""))

fit <- glm(highlow ~ V1 + V2 + V3 + V4 + V5 + V6 + V7 + V8 + V9 + V10,
       family="binomial", data=df)

library(car)
linearHypothesis(fit, c("V1-V2", "V2-V3"), c(0,0))


################
Linear hypothesis test

Hypothesis:
V1 - V2 = 0
V2 - V3 = 0

Model 1: restricted model
Model 2: highlow ~ V1 + V2 + V3 + V4 + V5 + V6 + V7 + V8 + V9 + V10

  Res.Df Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)
1    991                     
2    989  2 0.2761      0.871
```